# Domain (country) realted banners in PHP based system

Tags: php, dns, youtube, subdomain

I have an PHP based Youtube clone system installed on our server.

The same system is used in couple of countries. Let's say that I have 3 domains that all point to the same system:
*www.site.hr

www.site.ba

www.site.rs*

They all redirect to some site named *www.site.tv*

These 3 countries have very similar languages so it makes sense to have the same system for every country, but inside the system it would be great to display banners related to that particular country.

What is the best way to do that, and is it even possible?
My ideas were:
1) to lookup every visitors IP and check from which country is it or
2) to create 3 subdomains hr.site.tv, ba.site.tv and rs.site.tv, which are all
separate systems but share the same database...

I know that first idea is flawed, and second one is plausible.
Do you have any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a robust system but only add the possibility to set the banners for some (most) users, you might use that simple solution :

```
www.site.hr redirects to www.site.tv?lang=hr
www.site.ba redirects to www.site.tv?lang=ba
www.site.rs redirects to www.site.tv?lang=rs
```

then store the lang parameter in `$_SESSION` and use it to display the related banners as people keep visiting internal pages.

you'd need to have a default behaviour for the case when that parameter doesn't exist in session (for robots for instance).

you'll have the benefits of very little duplicate content and little change to the existing code (i suppose).

Comment: This is a really simple but elegant solution for my problem.
I have an issue for overcomplicating simple things.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

IP address lookup and GeoIP are not reliable. Sniffing $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] won't be of much help because they may return the same languages, or not at all if user prefers English, for example.

Using subdomains, or different URL paths within the same domain, is recommended if these are your in-house banners. Third-party ad providers may have their own market-targeting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

your idea 1) will probably work for most cases, but sometimes users will get the wrong one depending how they connect to the internet, and gives you problems with things like search engines which you might want to index all three sites.

2) Is problematic because of the 'all separate systems' part. Maintaining three separate codebases to do essentially the same thing is a waste of effort, and it will be tricky to make changes to the database structure if it has to be suitable for all of them.

A better option is to have just one system, but connect it to all three domains, and put some logic inside it to display the appropriate banner for each country. You can configure your web server to treat the three domain names as aliases and send requests from all of them to the same PHP application. In PHP you can get the name of the site the client requested as `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. You might be using a framework or PHP library that provides a different way to have domain name specific content on your site.

It's possible clients could send a hostname you aren't expecting, so make sure you have a whitelist of allowable hostnames and your server rejects the request if it gets something it doesn't recognise.